# Create a view to show active members in last 7 days

Tags: 7, views

I want to create a view that shows the number of unique users that posted a node or commented on a node in the last 7 days.

If I create a view of nodes and add "author" and "comments" relationships and then aggregate and show "distinct users" it will only show users that have created a node, not commented on a node.

If I create a view of users I can't add relationship for "nodes" or "comments".